# I am having trouble with switch statements specifically making them check my code over and over

Tags: javascript, variables, switch-statement, alert

***My code is only running my switch statement once and because of that the page doesn't refresh. This makes it so once the code is run you only have those three buttons to press while what I want it to do it to update the switch statement multiple times since my variable I am checking is updating.***

```
  let level = 1
    if (level === 1) {
      alert(level + '. You are walking down a path and see a shadowy figure emerge from the woods, what do you do?')
      switch (level) {
        case 1:
          var button = document.createElement("button");
          button.innerHTML = "Threaten";
          var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
          body.appendChild(button);
          button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert("You threaten the man but are put to the ground and stabbed, you wake up hours later in a shack on the ocean with a women standing over you what do you do?");
            level += 1

          });
          var button = document.createElement("button");
          button.innerHTML = "Flee";
          var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
          body.appendChild(button);
          button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert("You run like the wind to escape the man, you reach your house to tell your wife, she calls you crazy and leaves with your kids, what is your move?");
            level += 2
          });
          var button = document.createElement("button");
          button.innerHTML = "Attack";
          var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
          body.appendChild(button);
          button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert("You take out a knife and plunge it through his chest, he falls to the ground, blood seeping from his vest, you run away, what is your move as you escape into the forest?");
            level += 3
          });
          break;

        case 2:

          var button = document.createElement("button");
          button.innerHTML = "Pay";
          var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
          body.appendChild(button);
          button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert("did something");
          });
          var button = document.createElement("button");
          button.innerHTML = "Threaten";
          var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
          body.appendChild(button);
          button.addEventListener("click", function() {
            alert("did something");
          });

          break;
          default:
          alert('fail');
```

}
        };

***I set up the switch properly but it only running case 1 and is not looking back at case two even though the variable is updating. Do I have to put to switch statement in a for loop?***

Comment: you have to put it in a function, and define the changing variable outside of the function

Comment: This is not a clean-cut approach to implementing this VN-style algorithm. You have to contain your dialogue steps into functions/methods and move away from that switch case technique. I know this does not answer your question, but I guarantee your development will be much easier if you discontinue this approach.

Comment: Thanks that helps and when you say that do you mean declare them in HTML like:

Comment: <input type="button" value="..." function myFunction()>

Comment: thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this to shorten and simplify your code:

```js
var levels = [
 [
  'You are walking down a path and see a shadowy figure emerge from the woods, what do you do?',
  {'Threaten': 1, 'Flee': 2, 'Attack': 3}
 ],

 [
  'You threaten the man but are put to the ground and stabbed, you wake up hours later in a shack on the ocean with a women standing over you what do you do?',
  {'Die': 4}
 ],
 
 [
  'You run like the wind to escape the man, you reach your house to tell your wife, she calls you crazy and leaves with your kids, what is your move?',
  {'Die': 4}
 ],
 
 [
  'You take out a knife and plunge it through his chest, he falls to the ground, blood seeping from his vest, you run away, what is your move as you escape into the forest?',
  {'Die': 4}
 ],

 [
  'You cannot die!',
  {'Start Over': 0}
 ],
],

q = document.getElementById('q'),
b = document.getElementById('b'),

level = 0;

play(level);

function play(n = 0) {
 q.innerHTML = levels[n][0];
 b.innerHTML = '';

 for (var i in levels[n][1]) {
  var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.name = levels[n][1][i];
  button.innerHTML = i;
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){play(this.name)});
  b.appendChild(button);
 }
}
```

```html
<h3 id="q"></h3>
<div id="b"></div>
```